# Cakephp multiple belongsto fields

Tags: cakephp-1.3, belongs-to

I'm using Cakephp 1.3 and I've problem with multiple belongsTo relationship.
I have 3 tables Library, User, Address.

I use recursive on 2

UserModel:

```
var $belongsTo = array('address'=>array('className'=>'address','foreignKey'=>'users_id'));
```

LibraryModel:

```
var $belongsTo = array('user' => array('className'=> 'user','foreignKey'=>'user_id'));

function getUser($idBook)
    {
        $this->recursive = 2;
        return $this->find('all',
    array('conditions'=>array('library.book_id'=>$idBook),
'fields'=>array('user.id','user.nick','address.town')));
    }
```

It work only without fields param but I wanna select only this 3 columns. 
Please where's my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to use Containable instead http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Behaviors/Containable.html I'd also recommend using the lazy model plugin https://github.com/Phally/lazy_model

app_model.php

```
App::import( 'Lib', 'LazyModel.LazyModel' );
class AppModel extends LazyModel {
    var $actsAs = array( 'Containable' );
    var $recursive = -1;    
}
```

user.php

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'user';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Address' => array(
            'className' => 'Company',
            'foreignKey' => 'users_id'
        )
    );
}
```

library.php

```
class Library extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'library';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );

    function getUser( $idBook )
    {
        return $this->find( 'all', array(
            'conditions'=>array('library.book_id'=>$idBook),
            'contain' => array(
                'user' => array(
                    'address' => array(
                       'fields' => array( ... )
                    ),
                    'fields' => array( ... )
                )
            ),
            'fields' => array( ... )
        );
    }
}
```